# how to add multiple emails in CC while sending email in Maximo

Tags: java, email, maximo

We are using maximo 6.2.3 version. To send emails for a particular requirement we are using sendemail method in Mxserver class(psdi/server/Mxserver.class).

`sendEMail(String to, String from, String subject, String message)`

In mxserver class there is a also a method, where I can add multiple email addresses in **TO** .

```
sendEMail(String to[], String from, String subject, String message)
```

Method in mxserver class for adding one email address in TO and one cc

```
sendEMail(String to, String cc, String bcc, String from, String subject, String message)
```

My requirement is to add one email address in TO and multiple email addresses in CC. How I can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume there is nothing like `sendEMail(String to[], String from, String cc[], String subject, String message)` in the API, is there ?

Comment: If it is there I should have called that method right?

Comment: Yes. The most logical and straightforward solution for the problem would be to add a new method, similar to my above comment, to the API. But there is no such method in the API (as you mentioned).And I assume maximo is not an open source lib (as it looks like it is part of IBMs framework), I don't think you can easily add what you need to the API. So, I am sorry but I can't think about anything else atm. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I use it the following way and it works fine.

```
if(commSetRemote.count() > 0)
        {
            CommTemplate commRemote = (CommTemplate)commSetRemote.getMbo(0);
            SqlFormat sqf = new SqlFormat(getRoot(), commRemote.getString("subject"));
            sqf.setIgnoreUnresolved(true);
            String subject = sqf.resolveContent();
            sqf = new SqlFormat(this, commRemote.getString("message"));
            sqf.setIgnoreUnresolved(true);
            String message = sqf.resolveContent();
            if (message.length() > 0){
                message = message + "";
            }
            String emailList ((CommTemplateRemote)commRemote).convertSendTo("COMMTMPLT_TO", this);
            String sendTo = emailList;

            emailList = ((CommTemplateRemote)commRemote).convertSendTo("COMMTMPLT_CC", this);
            String cc = emailList;

            emailList = ((CommTemplateRemote)commRemote).convertSendTo("COMMTMPLT_BCC", this);
            String bcc = emailList;
            String sendFrom = commRemote.getString("SENDFROM");
            try {
                MXServer.sendEMail(sendTo, cc, bcc, sendFrom,subject, message, sendFrom, null, null);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```